# Return exists but it still says, "Nothing was returned from render."

Tags: reactjs

First of  all, I have try searching and reading similar questions. I have even found something very similar to my problem. But none helped.

So, I have this projected route component but its giving me this error.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const token = Cookies.get('token');
    const history = useHistory();

    const renderComp = (props) => {
        if (token) {
            return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
            return history.push('/');
        }
    };

    return <Route {...rest} render={renderComp} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And here is the component I am rendering through protected route,

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Greet() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please help, and explain why its happening. As far as I understand, I am returning something from the method. Then what?

Comment: It might possibly arise from `return history.push('/');`. That likely doesn't return anything, so React detects that "nothing" is being returned. Probably a better way is, in that else clause, to return a react router `Redirect` component: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I tried `<Redirect to="/" />`.

Comment: So, I was doing it in the wrong place. Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `renderComp` function to be like this:

```
const renderComp = (props) => {
    if (token) {
        return <Component {...props} />;
    } else {
        history.push('/');
        return null;
    }
};
```

A React component should return some jsx or null. So basically, instead of returning `history.push('/');` you need to return `null`. Because `history.push('/');` returns undefined, hence if you return `history.push('/');` you are returning undefined.

Comment: Unfortunately, its same even after applying your suggested changes.

Comment: Well then issue is somewhere else. Can you create a reproducible example on code sandbox or something.

Comment: Yes, please wait. I will post it here once I am done.

Comment: cool, bit busy at the moment. Will take a look later today

Comment: You have the same issue, but in another place too. In Login component you are returning `history.push('/')` [here](https://github.com/IamLizu/react-returnErr-reproduction/blob/9123913e882c7b0c11e57c431a20ebf1a711fbb4/src/components/Yolo.jsx#L42).  Use `<Redirect>` or return null;

Comment: Thanks. I also just noticed that and came to update the situation. Using Redirect in the referring component fixed the issue.